# MYSQL - GROUP BY - PHP query

Tags: php, mysql

Hello the group by on MYSQL is working but on PHP query i not working.

If i remove Group By from PHP is working but i dont take correct results.

MYSQL

```
SELECT _o.Ora,_u.Fname,_u.Sname,_u.Phone,_o.Name1,_o.Name2,_o.Name3,_o.Name4,_o.Name5,_o.Name6,_o.PaymentType,_o.FinalPrice
                FROM _orders as _o,_users as _u WHERE _o.ShopName='ISAAK' AND _o.HmerominiaParagelias='13/12/2018' AND _o.UserID=_u.Username 
                GROUP BY _o.OraParagelias IN (SELECT MAX(OraParagelias) FROM _orders) ORDER BY _o.Ora DESC;
```

Result

[image]

PHP Code:

```
<?php

    include_once 'connect.php';

    $ShopName= $_POST['ShopName'];
    $HmerominiaParagelias= $_POST['HmerominiaParagelias'];

    $sql = "SELECT _o.Ora,_u.Fname,_u.Sname,_u.Phone,_o.Name1,_o.Name2,_o.Name3,_o.Name4,_o.Name5,_o.Name6,_o.PaymentType,_o.FinalPrice
                FROM _orders as _o,_users as _u WHERE _o.ShopName='$ShopName' AND _o.HmerominiaParagelias='$HmerominiaParagelias' AND _o.UserID=_u.Username 
                GROUP BY _o.OraParagelias IN (SELECT MAX(OraParagelias) FROM _orders) ORDER BY _o.Ora DESC";

    $result = $dbcon->query($sql);


    if($result->num_rows> 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "\nΏρα: ".$row["Ora"]."\nΌνομα: ".$row["Fname"]."\nΕπώνυμο: ".$row["Sname"]."\nΤηλ.: ".$row["Phone"]."\n".$row["Name1"]."\n".$row["Name2"]."\n".
                    $row["Name3"]."\n".$row["Name4"]."\n".$row["Name5"]."\n".$row["Name6"]."\nΤρόπος Πλήρ.: ".$row["PaymentType"]."\nΤελικό Ποσό: ".$row["FinalPrice"].
                    "€?";
        }
    } else{
        echo "no_orders_found?";
    }

?>
```

[![enter image description here]

As result i take: no_orders_found

Any solution on how to fix group by on php?

Comment: Please post your code in the question not as an image.

Comment: There is no way that SQL can work in MySQL as `GROUP BY` does not take logical expressions. Carefully re-check if what you posted is **exactly** what you run to yield those records. I can see how if `GROUP BY` is replaced with `AND` or `OR` will work in MySQL.

Comment: @Parfait Is working for sure i have write and test it on MYSQL Workbench.

Comment: Please set up a reproducible example in [rextester.com](https://rextester.com/l/mysql_online_compiler), [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/), [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com), etc. I am very interested to see a `GROUP BY ... IN()` example! First I ever will see of it!

Comment: @Parfait Also just now try it on [rextester.com](https://rextester.com) ... and is working fine [image proof](https://imgur.com/C7gYrBD)

Comment: Wow! Indeed. I stand corrected: https://rextester.com/IGT47851. But with other engines: Postgres, SQL Server, Oracle the query fails as it should. More reasons to stay away from MySQL!

Comment: @parfait Yes i wanna return the newest record of a same user (p.g if a user make a new order show the newest order without the old on results)... i can post sql tables and inserts if you wanna help me.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a compliant ANSI SQL query using explicit `JOIN` between tables. Specifically, join on an aggregate query to connect user unit level data to their corresponding max value to return more than two users. Below assumes *UserID* is the unique value to use for joining (adjust as needed).

Likely, the reason for differences of query runs is the PHP DBI-API (mysqli, pdo, etc.) does not allow the strange (newer?) `GROUP BY ... IN()` whereas MySQL workbench apparently does, maybe with a specific setting turned on.

```sql
SELECT _o.Ora, _u.Fname, _u.Sname, _u.Phone, _o.Name1, _o.Name2, _o.Name3, 
       _o.Name4, _o.Name5, _o.Name6, _o.PaymentType, _o.FinalPrice
FROM _orders as _o,
INNER JOIN _users as _u 
   ON _o.UserID = _u.Username 
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT UserID, MAX(OraParagelias) AS Max_OraParagelias
    FROM _orders 
    GROUP BY userID
   ) AS m
  ON _o.userID = m.userID AND _o.OraParagelias = m.Max_OraParagelias
WHERE _o.ShopName = 'ISAAK' 
  AND _o.HmerominiaParagelias = '13/12/2018' 
ORDER BY _o.Ora DESC;
```

[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/VQSDJ85512) *(using sample data)*

Comment: Is working pefect thanks.... also one small detail `(SELECT m.UserID, MAX(OraParagelias) AS Max_OraParagelias  FROM _orders AS m  GROUP BY m.userID)` you probably forgot to put `AS m` on `_orders`

Comment: Great to hear! Actually, I did not mean to use the alias within the subquery only for the subquery.